# Accessing Dynamically loaded JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to access a dynamically loaded custom javascript into an `onSubmit` event handler.

So basically the code goes like this

```
onSubmitHandler() {
    var script1 = document.createElement("script");
    var script2 = document.createElement("script");

    script1.type = "text/javascript";
    script1.src = "file1.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script1)

    script1.onload = function () {
        script2.type = "text/javascript";
        script2.src = "file2.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script2);
    }

    script2.onload = function () {
        secondScriptFn() // This function is inside script2
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is, when I try to create the handler, it automatically states the `secondScriptFn` is not defined.

[image]

My goal is for the `secondScriptFn()` to be fired only when the `file2.js` is loaded.

Any thoughts?
Am I doing this wrong?

*Note: I'm developing this on Gatsby Framework as I am trying to port a JS script into React, cause directly loading the script does not work.*

Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: See edit to answer, if you haven't already - this is a *linter warning*, not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore your linter. The code will run as expected.

To trick out the linter you could also write (just syntactig sugar):

```
 window["secondScriptFn"]()
```

Comment: Do you know why the standalone line `secondScriptFn()` doesn't implicitly reference the window property, though? It's not like OP defined `secondScriptFn` in an inner scope and assigned it to `undefined`.

Comment: @snow whoops, actually this must be just a linter warning

Comment: The problem with it is, I was not able to proceed to check and test cause of this error. It's just displaying the error and not the page. So I'm pretty sure it's not just a linter warning

Comment: @lex so does it cause a runtime error or not? Or is it just not building ?

Comment: It's a compile time error. so when I run `gatsby develop` it throws this error

Comment: @lex then ignore this one